# list Pattern Matching to return a new list of every other element

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I need to write a function that takes a List such as ("1","2","3") and return every other element in that list into a new list using pattern matching. What would be the correct case statement to get the head element of the list and then find every other element.

```
def everyOther[A](list: List[A]): List[A] =
     list match {
     case   _ => Nil
     case x::xs => 
}
```

It should return a new list of every 2nd element starting from the head element

Answer (score 5):

Recursion to the rescue.

```
def everyOther[A](list: List[A]): List[A] = list match {
  case Nil => list
  case _ :: Nil => list
  case x :: _ :: xs => x :: everyOther(xs)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way that involves using `grouped` to capture every other elements of a list starting from its 1st element:

```
def everyOther[A](list: List[A]): List[A] =
  list.grouped(2).map(_.head).toList

everyOther(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
// res1: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 5)
```

To capture every other elements starting from the 2nd element, either replace the list with its `tail`:

```
def everyOther2[A](list: List[A]): List[A] =
  list.tail.grouped(2).map(_.head).toList
```

or, replace `map` with `collect` with a `case/match` partial function:

```
def everyOther2[A](list: List[A]): List[A] =
  list.grouped(2).collect{ case List(_, x) => x }.toList
```

Comment: Never mind, I missed the fact that you used `collect` and not `map`. This does work.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are great, but this kata is so fun, that I just wanted to add my own solution:

Create extractor object:

```
object EveryOther {
    def unapply[A](list: List[A]): Option[List[A]] = {
      Some(
         Stream.iterate(true)(!_) //create lazy infinite stream of true,false,true...
           .zip(list)
           .flatMap{
              case (true, x) => Some(x) //filter to take only odd tuples with true
              case _ => None   //could be replaced with Option.when from scala 2.13
           }.toList
         )    
    }
}
```

And then just use it in pattern matching:

```
List(1,2,3,4,5,6) match {
   case EveryOther(x) => println(x) //1,3,5
}
```